# Seeing a blank page on running Install.php?

Tags: php

I am running on localhost the installation of a php based website. I got the following error

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\testweb\install\install.php on line 65
```

Line 65 has

```
$Install =&new INSTALL();
```

I was told to remove the & have line 65 read `$Install =new INSTALL();` but then when I run install I just see a blank page and nothing more than that. Can somebody throw some light on this as to what is happening here and why I am seeing just a blank page.

My php version is 5.3.3 and I am running this on WAMP.

Comment: You should give us more information on what you're running, including the php error log. What exactly is the error after you've made the change? If error logging is not turned on, make sure to turn it on using: http://si.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: @KrofDrakula I am not getting any errors just warnings and notices, I was told to turn them off, when I did but then I see a blank page. is there a compatibility issue. I have php 5.3.3 and wamp on windows 7

Comment: @ThomasFrei I am serious about this. I just get warnings

Comment: Whats this Website called that you are trying to run ?

Comment: @ThomasFrei I am doing this on localhost so no link is available

Comment: What i mean is are you trying to run something like WordPress, Joomla or codeigniter ?. If so we can check if there's a compatibility with php versions. If it's something you coded yourself, then it would be helpfull if you posted the full warning messages and some code. Otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: @ThomasFrei: this is not any cms based website. I have all this n local machine and I need to deploy this. I was trying to  do some online debugging using this tool . Not sure if you can get something from here and help. http://codepad.org/SxJyjeoC Appreciate your help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15238/discussion-between-thomas-frei-and-mike)

Answer (score 0):

that means that function is deprecated. You probarly downloaded a old script/cms. Mostly its leak and there are other better scripts. I recommend to not use this script.

Comment: What the error actually means is that the `new` keyword cannot be used with the `byref` assignment. Just use `$Install = new INSTALL();` and it should work.

Comment: @KrofDrakula: thats what $Install = new INSTALL(); I have done. but I see a blank screen

Comment: what do you get when you add this on top of install.php : error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @jordi12100: I get 2 notices undefined index on line if ($_GET['step'] > 2 OR $_POST['step'] > 2)

Comment: @Mike Paste the complete list of errors, notices and warnings in your question, copy/pasted from your log, as well as the relevant code. Also, we need all the information on what exactly you're trying to run, stabbing in the dark like this won't get you or us anywhere.